# Javascript this scoping problem

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, this

I'm loading a csv file and parsing it. and I want the resulting array to be a member of a certain object, but it ends up undefined, becuase I'm not using the "this" keyword correctly.

```
function SimPlayer(){

    this.dataset = new Array();
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var dset = this.dataset;

    function handler(){
        if(client.readyState == 4){
            if(client.status == 200){
                //file is done loading
                //split by lines
                dset = client.responseText.split("\n");
                for(var i=0; i<dset.length; i++){
                    //split each line by commas
                    dset[i] = dset[i].split(",");
                    //convert to ints
                    for(var j=0; j<dset[i].length; j++){
                        dset[i][j] = parseInt(dset[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                //dset is defined here, no problem. It contains the data from the csv file
                console.log(dset[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    client.onreadystatechange = handler;
    client.open("GET", "http://nathannifong.com/LayerCake/simdata/rec0_i0.csv");
    client.send();

    this.check = function(){
        //does not work because this.dataset will be empty.
        console.log(this.dataset[0])
    }
}
```

assume I create an instance of SimPlayer, and then call check later (after the csv file has had time to load)

```
foo = new SimPlayer();
//....time passes....
foo.check();
```

foo.check() causes

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

How can I fix my code so that in check(), this.dataset will contain the data from the csv file?

Comment: where in your code are you setting anything to the actual `dataset` array?

Comment: Also, you may find [my answer to another question about prototypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653472/how-do-i-properly-code-a-javascript-property-and-method-using-the-prototype-fun/4653667#4653667) useful.

Comment: why aren't you assigning dset to this.dataset on load, instead of before?

Comment: If I refer to this.dataset within handler(), it isn't there, because in handler, this refers to client

Comment: `foo = new SimPlayer();` cannot be followed by `foo.check()` anyway, coz you need some time to do the AJAX, which A stands for "asynchronous".

Comment: @timdream No worries on the asynchronous stuff, I'm dealing with it, I just took it out of this problem to simplify it.

Comment: @zzzzBov I thought I was doing it when I set dset = whatever, but I wasn't. see comment on ChaosPandion's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to store a reference to the proper this binding:

```
var _this = this;
this.check = function(){
    //does not work because this.dataset will be empty.
    console.log(_this.dataset[0])
}
```

Comment: That's what I attempted to do on the lines: var client = new XMLHttpRequest(); var dset = this.dataset; because I was originally refferring to the MLHttpRequest instance by as this within handler, and the SimPlayer instance as this within SimPlayer. I can't refer to both at the same time, So I tried saving the proper binding. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Solved. I did it wrong. should have done: var sim = this; function handler(){ sim.dataset } instead of: var dset = this.dataset; function handler(){ dset }

Comment: Uh, this is being bound properly here due to the `foo.check()` call setting it to `foo`. The problem was indeed that `dset` was **not** a reference to `this.dataset` so the assignment inside the handler would only change the value of dset :)

Comment: AWESOME.  This was the exact same problem I had when I was working with something very similar.  Is there any document or page I can look at for more details about how this scoping works?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative option you may consider the following example:

```
this.check = (function(thus){
    return function() {//does not work because this.dataset will be empty.
       console.log(thus.dataset[0])
    };
})(this);
```

PS: I haven't read the original post entirely, my example - only an alternative way for the answer. You may find such code in many JavaScript examples. You should understand using closures.